# bold in math mode

Tags: vector, boldmath

I am looking to obtain a representation for the vector in this way

[image]

I have only managed to get these two ways. Another option would be to use \varoverrightarrow{A}, but the arrow gets longer and I can't make the letter bold.

[image]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}

\title{E71}
\author{ }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\LARGE
$\vv{A}$ %first way
$\va*{A}$ %second way

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `\bm` for bold math italic and avoid `physics`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[a]{esvect}

\newcommand{\gvv}[1]{\vv{\bm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\gvv{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside, note that `inputenc` is not needed if the file is UTF-8 encoded, but `fontenc` is needed for Spanish in order to select the T1 output encoding.

Comment: thanks!, I didn't know the use of \newcommand, it seems to be quite useful